# Find $\int_{3}^{5}\left(\sqrt{x+2\sqrt{2x-4}}+\sqrt{x-2\sqrt{2x-4}}\right)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate the integral $$\int_{3}^{5}\left(\sqrt{x+2\sqrt{2x-4}}+\sqrt{x-2\sqrt{2x-4}}\right)dx$$

I tried replacing $x$ by $x-5-3$ but this is not working,neither Simpsons approximation is working.Is my approach of solving wrong?Please guide me..

Comment: Look my answer, maybe works $u=x-2$.

Comment: In such cases the substitution is not $ x-5-3$ its $5+3-x$ right ?

Comment: vote for my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$\int_{3}^{5}\left(\sqrt{x+2\sqrt{2x-4}}+\sqrt{x-2\sqrt{2x-4}}\right)dx$$
Let, $2x-4=t^2\implies 2dx=2tdt$

$$=\int_{\sqrt2}^{\sqrt6}\left(\sqrt{\frac{t^2+4}{2}+2t}+\sqrt{\frac{t^2+4}{2}-2t}\right)tdt$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\int_{\sqrt2}^{\sqrt6}\left(\sqrt{t^2+4t+4}+\sqrt{t^2-4t+4}\right)tdt$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\int_{\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt6}\left(\sqrt{|t+2|^2}+\sqrt{|t-2|^2}\right)tdt$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\int_{\sqrt2}^{\sqrt6}\left(|t+2|+|t-2|\right)tdt$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\int_{\sqrt2}^{\sqrt6}|t+2|tdt+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\int_{\sqrt2}^{\sqrt6}|t-2|tdt$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\int_{\sqrt2}^{\sqrt6}(t^2+2t)dt+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\int_{\sqrt2}^{2}|t-2|tdt+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\int_{2}^{\sqrt6}|t-2|tdt$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\int_{\sqrt2}^{\sqrt6}(t^2+2t)dt+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\int_{\sqrt2}^{2}(-t^2+2t)dt+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\int_{2}^{\sqrt6}(t^2-2t)dt$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left[\frac{t^3}{3}+t^2\right]_{\sqrt2}^{\sqrt6}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left[-\frac{t^3}{3}+t^2\right]_{\sqrt2}^{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left[\frac{t^3}{3}-t^2\right]_{2}^{\sqrt6}$$

$$=\frac{6\sqrt 3+6\sqrt 2-2}{3}+\frac{2-\sqrt 2}{3}+\frac{6\sqrt 3-7\sqrt 2}{3}$$  $$=\frac{12\sqrt 3-2\sqrt 2}{3}$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $\sqrt{x+2\sqrt{2x-4}}=\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{x-2\sqrt{2x-4}}=\big|\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{2}\big|$ for all $x\in[3,5]$.  Separate the integral into two parts: one on $[3,4]$ and the other on $[4,5]$.

Answer (score 3):

We Can Write it as $\displaystyle \sqrt{x+2\sqrt{2x-4}} = \sqrt{\left(\sqrt{x-2}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^2+2\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{x-2}} = \sqrt{\left|\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{2}\right|^2} = \left|\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{2}\right|$

Similarly

$\displaystyle \sqrt{x+2\sqrt{2x-4}} = \sqrt{\left(\sqrt{x-2}\right)^2-+\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^2-2\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{x-2}} = \sqrt{\left|\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{2}\right|^2} = \left|\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{2}\right|$

So Integral Convert into $\displaystyle \int_{3}^{5}\left[\left|\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{2}\right|+\left|\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{2}\right|\right]dx$

So In $3<x<4\;,$

We have $\left|\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{2}\right| = \sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{2}$ and $\left|\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{2}\right| = -\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{2}$

and In $4<x<5\;,$

We  have $\left|\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{2}\right| = \sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{2}$ and $\left|\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{2}\right| = \sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{2}$

So we get Integral as $\displaystyle 2\int_{3}^{4}\sqrt{2}dx+2\int_{4}^{5}\sqrt{x-2}dx$

Now in Second Integral  Put $(x-2) = t^2$ and $dx = 2tdt$ and Changing Limit,

We get Integral $\displaystyle = 2\sqrt{2}\int_{3}^{4}dx+4\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{3}}t^2 dt = 2\sqrt{2}+4\left[\frac{t^3}{3}\right]_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{3}} = $

Comment: Could you clarify what's going on in the first equality? I just don't see how $x=(x-2)^2+(\sqrt2)^2$. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry actually it is $(\sqrt{x-2})^2$

Comment: @juantheron,answer is $2\sqrt2+\frac{4}{3}(3\sqrt3-2\sqrt2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=x-2$, then the integral is equivalent to
$$\int_{1}^{3}{\left(\sqrt{u+2-2\sqrt{2u}}+\sqrt{u+2+2\sqrt{2u}}\right)du}=\int_{1}^{3}{\left(\sqrt{(\sqrt{u}-\sqrt{2})^{2}}+\sqrt{(\sqrt{u}+\sqrt{2})^{2}}\right)du}$$
$$\int_{1}^{3}{\left(|\sqrt{u}+\sqrt{2}|+|\sqrt{u}-\sqrt{2}|\right)du}=\int_{1}^{2}{2\sqrt{2}}+\int_{2}^{3}{2\sqrt{u}du}$$
$$4\sqrt{3}-\dfrac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}=4\sqrt{3}+\dfrac{6}{3}\sqrt{2}-\dfrac{8}{3}\sqrt{2}=\dfrac{4}{2}(3\sqrt{3}-2\sqrt{2})+2\sqrt{2}$$